# How do you remove the "Localize" button from SDL Tridion SiteEdit 2009

Tags: tridion, siteedit

I am using SDL Tridion SiteEdit 2009, and would like to remove the Localize button from the ComponentPresentation rollover borders. I have done this in the past, but have no recollection of how I did it. Does anyone know how I may have achieved this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find this section in your SiteEdit.config file (typically in C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\SiteEdit 2009\SiteEdit\Application\Configuration):

```xml
<!-- ** Component Toolbar **
If @Visible is set to "false" the toolbar will not be available.
Under <ButtonsVisibility> you can specify the availability of each button. -->
<ComponentToolbar Visible="true">
    <ButtonsVisibility>
        <Save>true</Save>
        <Publish>true</Publish>
        <EditParent>true</EditParent>
        <Localize>true</Localize>
        <StartActivity>true</StartActivity>
        <FinishActivity>true</FinishActivity>
        <Refresh>true</Refresh>
        <Swap>true</Swap>
        <EditInPopup>true</EditInPopup>
    </ButtonsVisibility>
</ComponentToolbar>
```

And set the value of `<Localize>` to `false`.